# How do I make my NPM package show "npm WARN prefer global" when installing locally

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

Hard to google the subj — too many user questions, mine is about package development. I want a user of my package see *"npm WARN prefer global"* when installing it not globally.

I thought `npm install yo` used to have such a warning but now it does not. At least I cannot see it.

My environment:

```
  › npm --version
1.4.10
  › node -v
v0.10.28
```

Answer (score 12):

[Ben Fortune's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24245686/45375) specifies how **an npm package *author* can designate a package as preferring *global* installation** (by adding key-value pair `"preferGlobal": true` to the `package.json` file).

Sadly, as the OP herself points out in a comment, this is **NOT enough to *always* trigger a warning for users *installing* such a package *locally***.

As of npm 2.3.0, the behavior is as follows when installing a global-installation-preferred package locally, using `npm install <pkgName>` (i.e., without `-g`):

The **warning - `npm WARN prefer global <pkgName>@<ver> should be installed with -g` - is *only* triggered, if**:

- there is a **valid `package.json` file** in the current directory,
- **AND it contains a `dependencies` and/or `optionalDependencies` key** whose value is an object (whether empty or not) - unless the package at hand happens to be contained therein.

Pragmatically, this means that **you will NOT see the warning when running `npm install <pkgName>` (i.e., without `-g`) in the following scenarios**:

- in a directory that's not an npm package project (no `package.json` file).
- in an npm package-project directory that happens to have no *runtime* dependencies at all (no `dependencies` and/or `optionalDependencies` key - by contrast, keys `devDependencies` and/or `peerDependencies` alone do *not* trigger the warning).
- in an npm package-project directory that happens to have `pkgName` already installed as a (by definition local) *runtime* dependency (in key `dependencies` or `optionalDependencies`).

---

Note that even `--loglevel silly` does not alter this behavior, so there is **currently no way to enforce *unconditional* display of the warning**.

Designating a package as global does have one *unconditional* side effect, however: in the npm registry (http://npmjs.com), the installation command shown in the sidebar on the right for such a package is `npm install <pkgName> -g`; i.e., it does include the `-g`.
[*Update: This functionality broke some time ago and is still broken as of 14 Sep 2015 - see* https://github.com/npm/newww/issues/1017 ]

Comment: Nice breakdown! So convoluted.

Answer (score 9):

You need to specify

```
"preferGlobal": true
```

in your `package.json`.

[Documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#preferglobal)

Comment: Thanks. But not only. I found out that it only works if a user runs it into teh folder which has `package.json` file with `dependencies` field. Without such a field the flag does not work.

Comment: FYI: This option is now deprecated

Answer (score 0):

`preferGlobal` is now [deprecated](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#preferglobal):

> This option used to trigger an npm warning, but it will no longer
>   warn. It is purely there for informational purposes. It is now
>   recommended that you install any binaries as local devDependencies
>   wherever possible.